# T-SQL/PHP show strings that are over 70% similar to string A

Tags: php, sql-server, string, comparison, similarity

Here's something I have never done or even attempted to do, and now I need to:

I have a sample string, let's say the well know `$myVar = 'Hello World'`.
Than I have a DB table like this:

```
| ID | sample_string |
---------------------
| 1  | Hello World   |
| 2  | Hello Worlds  |
| 3  | Hello Word    |
| 4  | Hi Jack       |
---------------------
```

The next thing I need to do, is to get all records from DB table where data in field `sample_string` is similar in more than, let's say 70%, to `$myVar`. In this example Hello World, Hello Worlds & Hello Word.

This can be done directly in DB (MSSQL) or in PHP by comparing `$myVar` against each of table rows and building a PHP array, which ever works.

Any help or links to anything that may help are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I think I found it: php's *similar_text()*. I wonder what was wrong with my google questions that this has not come up before.

However if someone knows a way of doing this DB side (query or sp) please share.

Comment: You could try looking into SOUNDEX() and DIFFERENCE().

Comment: I did, but I specifically need to get the percentage value, and using soundex & difference does not provide me with it.